# flutter pub get error "is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec."

Tags: pubspec

good day
I have the following problem:

error on line 40, column 11: Invalid description in the "cdm_flutter_api" pubspec on the "plugincdm" dependency: "./lib/CdmPlugin/" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
╷
40 │ path: ./lib/CdmPlugin/
│ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

I have the following problem: in my initial project in pubspec.yaml I reference a dependency as follows

```
dependencies:
  plugincdm:
    path: ./lib/CdmPlugin/
```

and all correct

now in the second project I reference the first one in my pubspec.yaml as follows

```
dependencies:
  cdm_flutter_api:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/example/cdm_flutter_api.git
      ref: cdm-beta-1.0.0
```

and i have the following error

error on line 40, column 11: Invalid description in the "cdm_flutter_api" pubspec on the "plugincdm" dependency: "./lib/CdmPlugin/" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
╷
40 │ path: ./lib/CdmPlugin/
│ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵